# RUNNING socket.IO-objc IN background

Tags: ios, sockets, background

I am working in iOS app Development .I am using 
pkyeck/socket.IO-objc in my app to implement scoket connection. My Socket connections working well while the app running in foreground.but if my app goes to background the socket connections are stopped to work. please tell any suitable solutions to run app in background too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is in the project capabilities, it is called "Background mode" iirc. Here is a tutorial describing more details.

Basically, I suppose you want the "fetch" background mode.

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-whats-new-in-background-multitasking